# Flowplayer Rails Stuck

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, flowplayer

i'm stuck with a Rails application that uses flowplayer that plays flv files. 
I'm using the flowplayer gem [here](https://github.com/scottdavis/flowplayer-gem). I follow the instructions and the usage part where you have to choose between jQuery or Prototype comes with a bit of code. I don't know how to put this code, since i don't know its language. Is it Ruby code? jQuery code? 
Anyway, has anyone tried and succeed playing flash videos with this? I'd appreciate if someone could tell me what to do with that piece of code that's bugging me.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I update the question with the code in the view to narrow the problem.

```
<a href="<%= url_for(:controller => "attachments", :action => "public_download", :id => @attachment)%>"
id='video' style='display:block;width:512px;height:312px;'>
  <%= flowplayer_for :video, 'flowplayer.swf' do |player|%>
      <%- player.playlist [{:url => "video_still.jpg" }, {:url => "#{Rails.root}/public#{@attachment.arxiu.url}", :autoPlay => false, :autoBuffering => true }] %>
        <%- player.onLoad do %>
            <%- 'this.unmute();' %>
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
</a>
```

The first line is the url of the action. Meaning that if i click in the video I download it.
This action works, what it doesn't show is the player with the video. So i can narrow it to the code that comes from github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opted for deleting the gem and doing it via script. Now it works perfectly. It seems the gem didn't find the plugin or the file, if you kwow a little javascript I recommend you to do it via script, you'll save a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

This is ruby code. Although I haven't used the gem this code should go wherever you wish the flowplayer javascript tag to appear:

```
# params: container_element_id, player_path, library
flowplayer_for :video, '/flowplayer.swf', 'jquery' do |player| 
  player.playlist [{:url => "video_still.jpg" }, {:url => "video_512x288.flv", :autoPlay => false, :autoBuffering => true }]
  player.onLoad do 
    'this.unmute();'
  end
end
```

The source for the method is [here](https://github.com/scottdavis/flowplayer-gem/blob/master/lib/flowplayer/railties/helper.rb).

My 2c though is that you should use not use a plugin or a gem for this, flowplayer is quite easy to implement directly on your layout and views, and this way you are removing an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately plugins will be removed in the next Rails version, and i got rid of the plugins the previous projects used

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I mean NOT use a plugin or a gem

Comment: How can i do it then? Does Rails have a way of playing flash videos?

Comment: Well, this question is for getting the plugin to work. My code should sort that out. Regarding how to do it, you could just follow the plain  old HTML/JS instructions: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html

Comment: You're right, I'll try that and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Well, i tried it and it doesn't work, i'll update my question with the code in the view in case anyone sees something wrong.